# Watcher in vue.js won't receive value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, watch

Im using a watcher in vue for updating the values in the component **Persons.vue** as soon as an array Im passing from the **App.vue** to the **Persons.vue** as a prop changes. It works fine and updates when Im updating the prop by using the optionlist. But as soon as Im using a datepicker to set the a new date the array that is saved to the prop personData is updated correctly in the console log but is not received in the watcher.

Any hint of solving this is very much apreciated!

This is i fictive codesetup based on a much bigger application but I hope you get the problem.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <select @change="person($event)">
      <option :value="selectionOne">One</option>
      <option :value="selectionTwo">Two</option>
    </select>
    <flat-pickr v-model="initDate" :config="config" @on-change="changeTime"></flat-pickr>
  </div>
</template>
```

if I start with updating the person the value is sent to the watcher correctly but if I after that is running the changeTime function by changing the date the value is not sent to the watcher

```
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "selectionOne",
      selectionOne: "selectionOne",
      selectionTwo: "selectionTwo",
      personOne: [{ firstName: "XX" }, { born: "XXXX" }],
      personTwo: [{ firstName: "YY" }, { born: "YYYY" }],
      personData: []
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.personData = [{ firstName: "XX" }, { born: "XXXX" }];
  },

  methods: {
    // if I start with updating the person the value is sent to the watcher correctly
    person(e) {
      this.selected = e;
      this.updateNames(e);
    },
    // but if I after that is running the changeTime function by changing the date the value is not sent to the watcher
    changeTime(selectedDates) {
      this.born = this.timeFormatter(selectedDates[0]);
      this.updateNames(this.selected);
    },

    updateNames(e) {
      this.selected = e;
      let selection = e.target.value.split(",");
      if (selection == "selectionOne") {
        this.personData = this.personOne;
        // updating the second position with new born object
        this.personData[1] = { born: this.born };
      }
      if (selection == "selectionTwo") {
        this.personData = this.personTwo;
        this.personData[1] = { born: this.born };
      }
      console.log(this.personData)
    }
  }
};
```

**Persons.vue**

```
export default {
  name: "Persons",
  props: {
    personData: {
      type: Array
    }
  },

  watch: {
    personData: {
      deep: true,
      immediate: true,
      handler(newValue) {
        try {
          console.log("newValue", newValue);
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("no data yet ...");
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: this.updateSensorvalues? 
where does this method appear?

Comment: I've got some concerns around your setup. I see you're using `personOne: [{ firstName: "XX" }, { born: "XXXX" }],` instead of something like `personOne: { firstName: "XX" , born: "XXXX" }` while this can work, it usually requires more logic for managing the data. Also you end up nesting the data, which makes reactivity more complicated, and more likely to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `this.$set` like this:

```js
updateNames(e) {
  this.selected = e;
  let selection = e.target.value.split(",");
  if (selection == "selectionOne") {
    this.personData = this.personOne;
    // updating the second position with new born object
    this.$set(this.personData, 1, { born: this.born });
  }
  if (selection == "selectionTwo") {
    this.personData = this.personTwo;
    this.$set(this.personData, 1, { born: this.born });
  }
  console.log(this.personData)
}
```

But you might want to re-evaluate your setup. Storing the data as an object in an array, copied from another array, seems like a cumbersome way to handle this data.